# Running first playbook program via jenkins hitting unable to connect to host

Tags: ansible

i need your help. I am a newbie to ansible. I read the doc but still not so clear. I have below playbook and inventory. When i execute it i am getting error

fatal: [152.32.97.23]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Data could not be sent to remote host \"152.32.97.23\". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh: ssh: connect to host 152.32.97.23 port 22: Connection timed out\r\n", "unreachable": true}

When connecting to ssh i need to specify password but in the plabook where should i specify it and i want the password to be encrypted via the use of vault. I really not sure how this can be done. Plase friends help me.

my-firstplaybook.yml

```
---
- hosts: app-server-grp
  user: sshusername
  tasks:
    - name: Check configuration
      command: ifconfig
```

my-host-inventory.yml

```
[app-server-grp]
152.32.97.23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that your very first problem is that you cannot reach your host at all from your Jenkins server. So you first need to sort that out before your can even worry about setting the password.

---

## Setting the password

The password should be part of your inventory. You can set the password for all machines, a specific group, or a specific host. I suggest you read in depth [how to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) to get a better understanding of the concepts. In the below example, I will set the password for the scpecific host.

The cleanest way IMHO, starting from your above inventory, at the same level create a `host_vars` directory and inside a `152.32.97.23.yml` file which will contain:

```
---
ansible_password: yourpassword
```

From now, the password will be used to connect to your host.

## Encrypting the password

If you want to vault encrypt this password (which is a good idea) you have 2 choices:

1. encrypt the complete `host_vars/152.32.97.23.yml` file. This can be done in place with the following command:

   ```
   ansible-vault encrypt host_vars/152.32.97.23.yml
   New Vault password: 
   Confirm New Vault password: 
   Encryption successful
   ```
2. only encrypt the password string in the file. First issue the command:

   ```
   ansible-vault encrypt_string yourpassword
   New Vault password: 
   Confirm New Vault password: 
   !vault |
         $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
         35653633333836356339363831653836313264356634316266376137356338653337373261323030
         6232613832633337383561313238383437303236396230660a663163363838626665356630363766
         61343265666337323935363063343537623137636330393762336234386339646663366135386561
         6366653738616563360a383138646439643436383366623236333334373466393036636263303035
         6331
   Encryption successful
   ```

   Then copy the encrypted string in your host_vars file which will now look like this:

   ```
   ---
   ansible_password: !vault |
         $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
         35653633333836356339363831653836313264356634316266376137356338653337373261323030
         6232613832633337383561313238383437303236396230660a663163363838626665356630363766
         61343265666337323935363063343537623137636330393762336234386339646663366135386561
         6366653738616563360a383138646439643436383366623236333334373466393036636263303035
         6331
   ```

   *(Note: I used the vault password `test` in the above example if you want to play with the file)*

Whatever solution you used, you can now use the encrypted password but you will need to provide the vault password. The simplest way is to provide it interactively using the `--ask-vault-pass` parameter. You should also read in depth [the vault documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html) for other ways to provide the password, use multiple ids if needed, edit, decrypt, recrypt....

## Using your vault encrypted data from jenkins

I will not got in depth in the solution here but it is perfectly possible. You will have to create a vault type credential first then reference that credential in you job to decrypt the data.

Comment: thanks alot. this information really helps. i appreciate your efforts.

Comment: can i know i reference the host_vars in the playbook . am i correct under var_files.

Comment: there is nothing to do. Read the doc for inventories. Simply use your inventory file as you did before. All the rest is automatic